# Referencing Non-Global Variable for Timer JS

Tags: javascript

I have this function.

```
function changeFrame(){
    var time = setInterval(start, 250);
}
```

and I want to stop it from firing in another function, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop it from firing in another function"?

Comment: make changeFrame return the interval identifier. Don't store it in a function-local variable time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to JS, I'm trying to call clearInterval in another function for the id of my setInterval.

Comment: Try returning the interval. `function changeFrame() { return setInterval(start, 250) }` and use it like `var timer = changeFrame(); clearInterval(timer);` or pass it to a function such as `function stopFrameChange(timer) { clearInterval(timer); } stopFrameChange(changeFrame());`

Comment: @AdrianCooney ah ok, this answers my question, I wasn't sure how to use return in JS, Would check this off as a solution if i could :).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
function changeFrame(){
    var time = setInterval(function() {
        // Do stuff
    }, 250);
}
```

Think it's in the comments.

Ok amended the fiddle to do what you want. I made time a global var. Call clearInterval in stop with the global var http://jsfiddle.net/QNWF4/3/

Comment: Well, I have a button, that starts something, and then I have a stop button that stops it from continuing, but I can't figure out how to word that inside my code.

Comment: Suggest a fiddle might be in order to figure this out.

Comment: I've never used this website before, but I think this should work.
http://jsfiddle.net/QNWF4/2/

Comment: I've actually put in this exact code myself before, maybe... I don't know the answer im looking for. I wanted the start() method to stop doing what it does.

Comment: So you could use setTimeout. This executes code after a specified time period only once. setInterval repeats until cleared.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call clearInterval you need to have the handle returned by setInterval.  That means something will either be global to the page or global to a containing function in which your script resides.

```
function Timer()
{ 
    var handle = null;
    this.start = function (fn,interval) {
        handle = setInterval(fn,interval);
    };
    this.stop = function ()
    {
        if (handle) { clearInterval(handle); handle = null; }
    };
    return this;
}
```